# solving absolute equation

Tags: analysis, inequality

Which number can be $x$?

$$\vert 1-\vert x-1\vert\vert\lt1$$

I got:

$$1-x+1=0 \Longrightarrow \boldsymbol{x_1} = 0$$
$$-1+x-1=0\Longrightarrow \boldsymbol{x_2} =  2$$

What is the method of calculation?

**THANKS**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have $|1-|x-1||\lt 1$ if and only if
$$-1\lt 1-|x-1| \lt 1.$$
Subtract $1$ from each expression.  So our inequalities are equivalent to
$$-2 \lt -|x-1| \lt 0,$$
or equivalently
$$0\lt |x-1| \lt 2.$$
The part $0\lt |x-1|$ is no problem, it holds everywhere except at $x=1$. So you are down to a familiar inequality $|x-1|\lt 2$, with the proviso that $x\ne 1$.

**Another way:** Our inequality holds if and only if
$$(1-|x-1|)^2\lt 1.$$
Expand the square, and do some algebraic simplification. We arrive at the inequality 
$$|x-1|^2 \lt |x-1|.$$
Remembering that we cannot have $x=1$, we can cancel and arrive at $|x-1|\lt 2$, again, familiar territory. This says that the distance of $x$ from $1$ is $\lt 2$. So $-1\lt x\lt 3$, with $x\ne 1$. Alternately, we can give the answer by saying that $x$ satisfies the inequality if $x$ is in the interval $(-1,1)$ or the interval $(1,2)$.